# QGIS .asc header

Tags: qgis, ascii

I have two .asc that I would like to aggregate (with a python's script) but the problem is:

The header are different because the cellshape are different and I would like to modify the cellshape of one of them, to make it square (I know that it will input a distortion) with QGIS.

I probably don't use the right "language" to explain my problem so:

Actual header of my .asc:

```
ncols
nrows
xllcorner
yllcorner
dx
dy
NODATA_value
```

The header of my .asc I would like:

```
ncols 
nrows 
xllcenter 
yllcenter 
cellsize 
nodata_value
```

Comment: Edit dx=dy and cells will be square.

Comment: If you edit the header you are effectively lying to the computer about where the data is. You shouldn't do that. If the cells aren't square then don't try and make them square by editing the header. You maybe need to *reproject* or *coordinate transform* data sets to work with them together.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Use the [GDAL/Raster Projections/Warp (reproject)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterprojections.html#gdalwarpreproject) processing tool.  This will resample the pixels. Below I've used "Nearest Neighbour" resampling (appropriate for categorical or integer rasters), but there are other resampling algorithms available in the tool that may be more appropriate for your data.

input.asc

```
ncols        512
nrows        512
xllcorner    1461344.000
yllcorner    -4036447.000
dx           9.000
dy           11.000
```

output.asc

```
ncols        461
nrows        563
xllcorner    1461344.000
yllcorner    -4036445.000
cellsize     10.000
```

[image]

You can then manually edit the output.asc to change x/yllcorner to x/yllcenter and add 1/2 pixel size to each of those values:

output.asc

```
ncols        461
nrows        563
xllcenter    1461349.000
yllcenter    -4036440.000
cellsize     10.000
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works but I still need to have xllcenter and yllcenter and not xllcorner and ycorner. Your reply was really helpfull thanks.

Comment: You can edit the header of the output, see edit